# Prevent "new app for this file type" notification

Tags: windows-10, file-management, windows-store-app

I'm on Windows 10 and I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 to make a metro/windows-store app. The app that I'm making is set to allow permissions to use certain file types (like .png, .bmp, .txt etc). I have to do this since it's a security requirement that all windows store apps must declare the file types that they will use beforehand.

The problem is, every time I debug this app, my file types are reset. So when I try to open a .png image (i.e. manually, through explorer), it notifies me that there are new apps that can open this file type and whether I want to use those. How can I prevent this ?

`tl;dr` How can I prevent files from notifying me about new apps that can open this file-type each time I try to open them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a checkbox at the bottom of the screen I'd mentioned that says 'Always use this app to open files of this file type'.